# My animated div glitches upwards than back down during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have made a basic div with a header and a paragraph inside of it and when I perform a multistep animation, the box glitches upwards than moves back down. It makes it look very glitchy and strange. You can view my error at https://jsfiddle.net/yajuy8qy/.
Code:

```
<div class="enlarge">
    <h1 class="title">Welcome!</h1>
    <p>Zach</p>
    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".enlarge").animate({minHeight: '500px'}, "slow");
$(".enlarge").animate({width: '80%'}, "slow");
}); 
</script>
<style>
.enlarge {
height: 500px;
width: 50%;
background-color: #2098D1;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
border-radius: 15px;
position: relative;
margin: 10px auto;
}
</style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the default padding property.  Try setting the padding on the div (even 1px appears fixes the glitch).

```
.enlarge{
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Comment: nice, anyway this is some kind of jQuery bug (just a little bit) because when using CSS transition, it just works without any glitch.